# Writing Assembler Code System Programming

Tags: assembly, system

I am working on writing an assembler code. For PASS # 1 I am following all instructions but stuck at the following point 
**Rule when opcode = 'BYTE'**

```
if OPCODE=‘BYTE’ then
            begin
                  find length of constant in bytes
                  add length to LOCCTR
            end {if BYTE}
```

It says if OPCODE = 'BYTE'  then find length of constant and add to Location counter (LOCCTR). I didn't got this step. Can some one clarify it to me please.

I also have this sample input program and its output.

**Input Program Below**

```
PROG START 0
FIRST STL RETADDR
SECOND LDA =CꞌABCDꞌ
THIRD LDA =XꞌFFꞌ
J @RETADR
DEF BYTE CꞌDEFꞌ
SYM1 EQU 512
```

**Output of the above program**

```
LINE# LOCCTR  LABEL     OPERATION    OPERAND
01    00000   PROG      START        0
02    00000   FIRST     STL          RETADDR
03    00003   SECOND    LDA          =C’ABCD’
04    00006   THIRD     LDA          =X’FF’
05    00009             J            @RETADR
06    0000C   DEF       BYTE         C’DEF’
07    00200   SYM1      EQU           512
08    0000F   SYM2      EQU           *
09    00003   SYM3      EQU          SECOND-FIRST
10    0000F   RETADDR   RESW         1
11    00012             END          FIRST
12    00012   *         =C’ABCD’
13    00016   *         =X’FF’
```

Program Length = (12 – 0) + 5 = 17

You can see above **when we Reach to Line 6   which contains Byte in the next line the LOCCTR movies to 00200.** I am not sure how it happened. Please explain it. Thanks

Comment: If `00200` is not a misprint then perhaps it's a special value to indicate that `SYM1`, being a constant, isn't actually stored anywhere. Or perhaps constants are stored starting at location `00200`? Re-read your instructions.

Comment: Can you please explain me the rule above that if opcode = BYTE then what to do ? I am not getting the rule exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EQU` instruction is a compile-time instruction that doesn't put anything in memory. It just sets the symbol on the left to the value on the right. If that value is an asterisk (*), then the value is the current value of `LOCCTR`. Instead of putting the current location in the `LOCCTR` column, these instructions display the value assigned to them (in hex). So the `00200` is just hex for `512`. Similarly, the `0000F` for `SYM2` is the current location that was assigned to `SYM2`. And the `00003` beside `SYM3` is the value of `SECOND-FIRST`, which are the addresses of the first and second instructions.

The `BYTE` instruction is a compile-time instruction that loads data into memory starting at the current location. The rule simply says to add the length of the data to `LOCCTR` in order to determine where the next part of the program will go.

Notice that line 6, a `BYTE` instruction, starts at location `0000C` and contains the string `'DEF'`. That's 3 characters. `0000C + 3` is `0000F`, which is the next `LOCCTR` value after the `EQU` instructions (which don't put anything in memory).

Comment: Ignoring the 00200 case I think I am getting your point. Just can you please also explain me the Line 9 and 10 of the output that how the LOCCTR  value changes to 3 and F respectively. Thank You

Comment: @farhangdon I figured out what the `00200` is. See updated answer.

Comment: It seems you turned me in the Right direction. Thanks a lot :)
Also if You could tell me how the Program Length = (12 – 0) + 5 = 17  is calculated. It will be great. Thanks

Comment: @farhangdon The location of `END` (hex `12`) minus the location of `START` (0) plus the size of the data at the end (4 bytes for `=C'ABCD'` and 1 byte for `=X'FF'`).